# Swiftui How can you use on Tap Gesture for entire row in a foreach loop

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-view

I am creating a SearchBar right now that gets data from API, the Text highlighted in red ( see image below) is what I want to pass into my userDefault string on tap . This is working as long as I tap the highlighted red text, is it possible to get that value when you tap anywhere in that row like say the white space ? any suggestions would be great .

```
@State var model: [SearchModel]
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
@State var isOpen: Bool = false
```

Above is my State variables and my user default . I won't show the whole code since the issue is only with the below . As you can see my values are in the **foreach**  I just want to have it so that if a user clicks on the white space of the row that I can still execute this code .

```
                     .onTapGesture {
                                      isOpen = true
                                     // I set the value here
                                    defaults.setValue(value.name, forKey: "location") 
                                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen, content: MainView.init)
```

The code above gives me the correct value but it's tied to the Text

```
       ZStack {
                Color(UIColor.white)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(model) { value in
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(value.name)
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .background(Color.red)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 10.0)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            isOpen = true
                        // I set the value here
                                            defaults.setValue(value.name, forKey: "location") 
                                        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen, content: MainView.init)
                          
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    Text(value.statelong)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                
                            }
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Divider()
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }.padding(.leading, 20.0)
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
            .listRowInsets(.none)
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It only works for the highlighted text because the `onTapGesture` is on the Text view.

**1. Using a `HStack()`** 
 
I would embed the **`VStack`** in a **`HStack`** and add a **`Spacer()`** to fill the entire area, then place the **`onTapGesture`** to the **`HStack`**, like this:

```
    ForEach(model) { value in
                HStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(value.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .padding(.trailing, 10.0)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text(value.statelong)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    isOpen = true
                    defaults.setValue(value.name, forKey: "location")
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen, content: MainView.init)
            }
```

**2. Using a **`ZStack()`****

Or you could use a **`ZStack`** to make a full view background and place the onTapGesture on the **`ZStack`**, add **`.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`** to the **`ZStack`** to fill the entire available width, like this:

```
 ForEach(model) { value in
                ZStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(value.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .padding(.trailing, 10.0)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text(value.statelong)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.contentShape(Rectangle())
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isOpen = true
                    defaults.setValue(value.name, forKey: "location")
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen, content: MainView.init)
            }
```

Comment: You probably need to attach `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to HStack/VStack before `.onTapGesture`.

Comment: The Spacer() in the first solution does the trick!

Answer (score 15):

Just add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` ViewModifier to your `HStack`, and nothing else